# Python multiprocessing with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, multiprocessing, object-detection

this is my first question on here and i am currently struggling with the usage of processes with python. Basically, in my main im starting two processes, one is a writing one that waits for 4 frames in order to write them together in one video continuously. The other one is the main process, which loads a YOLO Model via openCV (cv2.readNetFromDarkent(yoloConfig, yoloWeights)). So actually i am loading 4 models because i am starting 4 processes here where each process works with this model, since i cant use one model in 4 processes (i think). Each of those 4 processes gets their own video to read and detect objects in it and some other logic also happens inside with the found objects.

Before i switched to multiprocessing though it worked without a problem but now that i switched to multiprocessing in order to make it faster im suddenly getting the following error when trying to run my code. I am kinda hung up on the part that says:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 'cv2.dnn_Net' object
```

I havent found anything regarding this error but my guess is that processes do not share memory while threads do, that would be the reason why it worked before. But i can't wrap my head around what could be the problem now. Would i need to make global variables, which i have learned is a bad thing but i just want to make a proof of concept that i can simultanously work with multiple videos and detect objects from those. But now i am quite lost since i cant get it running this way.

Does anyone know if it is possible to be running 4 videos through an object recognition model like YOLO simultanously? I am missing experience with python to find a solution myself..

```
[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...
[INFO] YOLO loaded - took 45.8315 seconds
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\My Drive\BAK\implementation\yolo-opencv-objectdetection\yolo_video.py", line 413, in main
    front.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'cv2.dnn_Net' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 107, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\My Drive\BAK\implementation\yolo-opencv-objectdetection\yolo_video.py", line 354, in writer
    while not (eventFront.is_set() and eventBack.is_set() and eventLeft.is_set() and eventRight.is_set()):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\synchronize.py", line 329, in is_set
    if self._flag.acquire(False):
KeyboardInterrupt
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 357, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 108, in wait
    res = _winapi.WaitForSingleObject(int(self._handle), msecs)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: you're correct in thinking that multiprocessing does not share memory like threads do

Comment: Please provide a sample code so we can see how you instantiate and load these models and do you pass data if any between the processes.

Comment: wouldn't threads work ? opencv is a native module and probably releases the GIL so multiprocessing may not be useful

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, they would quite well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah as i have written it worked as i wanted when i used threads and for now i will just stick to it, but those threads arent running parallel then, which was my goal.

Comment: if you can provice a [mre] maybe we can help you to speed it up. You have to [edit] your post.